# Decrease TabbarItem Title Font Size

Tags: iphone

I have created UITabbarcontroller application...

In that application, I was set an title and image at run time in the tabbar item....
Some text should be larger compare to tabbar item...

Can any one help me ?

How can i fix this ?

Is it possible to done it any other way ?

Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 0):

Do you want each tabbar item's label to have different font size?

This cannot be done through any simple property settings.
Even though you could subclass TabbarController and achieve what you want, i wouldn't recommend it. (Mainly because, it wouldn't be pretty and will be inconsistent UI, unless you pull a kickass tabbar out of this experiment)